# ¿Como sumo meses o años a una columna de un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

me gustaría saber como puedo sumar años o meses a un DataFrame...

Intente hacerlo con dateutil.relativedelta:

```
PND2['INICIO_ENDOSO'].head() + relativedelta(years=1)
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'relativedelta'

El usar Timedelta no me es suficiente debido a que lo que busco es sumar meses o años, y no solo días...

Agradeceré sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás intentando aplicar `relativedelta` de forma vectorizada, es decir a cada elemento de la serie. A diferencia de la mayoría de métodos de pandas o numpy, `relativedelta` no está implementada para ser aplicada de forma vectorizada, sino sobre un solo objeto datetime.

Primero un ejemplo mínimo para reproducirlo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> PND2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {'INICIO_ENDOSO': pd.to_datetime(
            ["2021-11-17", "2022-05-21", "2024-03-07"])}
    )

>>> PND2

  INICIO_ENDOSO
0    2021-11-17
1    2022-05-21
2    2024-03-07
```

Para usar `relativedelta` puedes usar [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

>>> PND2["INICIO_ENDOSO"].map(lambda date: date + relativedelta(years=1))

0   2022-11-17
1   2023-05-21
2   2025-03-07
Name: INICIO_ENDOSO, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Pero pandas proporciona [`pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) que permite vectorizar la operación:

```
>>> PND2["INICIO_ENDOSO"] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)

0   2022-11-17
1   2023-05-21
2   2025-03-07
Name: INICIO_ENDOSO, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias crack!